# Rails How to pass params in cross model system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am unable to figure out the method to pass params to a link tag. What I want to do is When someone clicks on the Join Group link, the Membership model shall have a new row with group_id as the current group id and the user id as the current user id. The Membership model currently consists of two columns : user_id and group_id that maps users to groups. Can anyone help me with the mistake I am making.
Here is the code
Groups : show.html.erb

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @group.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Desc:</strong>
  <%= @group.desc %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Creator:</strong>
  <%= @creator.first_name %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Join Group', memberships_path(:group_id => @group.id, :user_id => current_user.id ), method: :post %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(@group) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
```

and here is the Memberships controller

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_membership, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /memberships
  # GET /memberships.json
  def index
    @memberships = Membership.all
  end

  # GET /memberships/1
  # GET /memberships/1.json
  def show
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@membership.user_id)
    @group = Group.find(@membership.group_id)
  end

  # GET /memberships/new
  def new
    @membership = Membership.new
  end

  # GET /memberships/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /memberships
  # POST /memberships.json
  def create
    @membership = Membership.new(membership_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @membership.save
        format.html { redirect_to @membership, notice: 'Membership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @membership }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @membership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /memberships/1
  # PATCH/PUT /memberships/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @membership.update(membership_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @membership, notice: 'Membership was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @membership }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @membership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /memberships/1
  # DELETE /memberships/1.json
  def destroy
    @membership.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to memberships_url, notice: 'Membership was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_membership
      @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def membership_params
      params.require(:membership).permit(:user_id, :group_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a method in your controller that handles adding a user to a group, something like:

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def join_group
        @user = User.find(params[:user]
        @user.group_id = params[:group_id].to_i
    end

    ...

end
```

Then routes.rb needs a path to that controller method:

```
get 'memberships/join_group' => 'memberships#join_group'
```

which will result in a path like `memberships_join_group_path` that you will use in your link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'Join Group', memberships_join_group_path(:group_id => @group.id, :user_id => current_user.id ) %>
```

The path you're currently using is sending params to your `index` method.

Comment: But this will not store it to the Membership database.

Comment: Isn't that an issue for you to resolve? You said your problem was passing params via link_to, which I answered. If you can't come up with the logic in your join_group method, that's a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to rails. I am trying def join_group
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        Membership.new( user_id: current_user.id, group_id: @group.id)
        Membership.save
    end

Comment: Then instead of a join_group method, you need to use new_membership_path, not membership_path and put the logic you've defined in your comment in there. You can ignore the part about changing routes, since you should already have a path to the new method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def create

    @member = current_user.members.build(:group_id => params[:group_id])
    if @member.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have joined this group."
      redirect_to members_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to join."
      redirect_to members_path
    end
  end
```

and use memberships instead of members